# How to handle format specifiers in TimeSpan.TryParseExact(...)

Tags: c#, .net, format-string

I'd like to parse a time span string that contains format specifiers into a [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.8). For example: `"2h 57m 43s"`. h, m, and s are all format specifiers. See [Custom TimeSpan format strings - .NET | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings?view=netframework-4.8) for more info.

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings?view=netframework-4.8#other-characters):

> Any other unescaped character in a format string, including a white-space character, is interpreted as a custom format specifier. In most cases, the presence of any other unescaped character results in a FormatException.
>
> There are two ways to include a literal character in a format string:
>
> - Enclose it in single quotation marks (the literal string delimiter).
> - Precede it with a backslash ("\"), which is interpreted as an escape character. This means that, in C#, the format string must either be @-quoted, or the literal character must be preceded by an additional backslash.

I've tried: `"hh'h 'mm'm 'ss's'"` and `@"hh\h mm\m ss\s"` with no luck.

```cs
TimeSpan tracker;
if (TimeSpan.TryParseExact("2h 57m 43s", @"hh\h mm\m ss\s", null, out tracker))
{
    Console.WriteLine(tracker);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("fail");
}
```

This always fails. I'm expecting a TimeSpan of `02:57:43`. I'm currently working around this issue using a Regex, but would like to know how can I parse this string using TryParseExact?

Comment: seems strange that you referenced the docs that said you need to escape literal characters including whitespace, and then didn't escape the space characters as it suggested. Also, you only have a single digit hour, so this should work: `@"h\h\ mm\m\ ss\s"`

Comment: @RufusL yup - just wasn't escaping the spaces. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `%` after the format specifier and you need to escape the space literals.

```
TimeSpan.TryParseExact("2h 57m 43s", @"h%\h\ m%\m\ s%\s", null, out tracker)
```

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/azcpRB)

Comment: Wow, it really was just the spaces. `@"h\h\ m\m\ s\s"` works too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Minor update in your code:

```
TimeSpan tracker;
if (TimeSpan.TryParseExact("02h 57m 43s", @"hh\h' 'mm\m' 'ss\s", null, out tracker))
{
    Console.WriteLine(tracker);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("fail");
}
```

The issue was it could not understand the space and also two times 'h' was not matching to the value.

I hope it helps!